# How to use document AND class as selector with Jquery .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery

As i have dynamic added content i need to use "document" as the selector for my event.

```
$(document).hover(function(){
  //Do something
}
```

Now i'd like to know if i can also use a class as a selector?
I tried:

```
$(document).hover('.liDoc', function(){
    $(this).children('.delDoc').css('color', 'red'); console.log($(this).children('.delDoc'))
}, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $(this).children('.delDoc').css('color', '');
});
```

This one don't work! It seems like whole document is target.
When using `.on()` i can do it like this...but `.on('hover')`is deprecated?!

Comment: you can still use `"mouseenter mouseleave"`, what got deprecated was the shorthand http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate `mouseenter/mouseleave` events and filter by type event, e.g:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.liDoc', function(e) {
  $(this).children('.delDoc').css('color', e.type === "mouseenter" ? 'red' : '');
});
```

But you would have better to toggle a class instead:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.liDoc', function(e) {
  $(this).children('.delDoc').toggleClass('colored');
});
```

with in CSS:

```
.delDoc.colored {
  color: red;
}
```

OR just use CSS if your use-case is simple as the one you posted:

```
.liDoc:hover > .delDoc {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Very well explained!

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        }, function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hover the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't delegate events here

Comment: on which event?

Comment: OP wants to delegate `.hover()` method which is shorthand for `mouseenter/mouseleave`. I don't see how your answer is any relevant there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class name as the selector directly.

Of course, you need to import the jQuery library first for this to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min"></script>
```

If you already downloaded the jQuery library (recommended) then the "src" value should lead to the file. If not, you can reference it directly with the URL above.

And now, your jQuery codes

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".liDoc").hover(function(){
            //mouse is in.. Do something
            $(this).children(".delDoc").css("background","red");
        }, function(){
            //mouse is out.. Do something
            $(this).children(".delDoc").css("background","transparent");
        });
    });
</script>
```